# Web service - current time zone for a city?

Tags: web-services, timezone

Is there a web service of some sort (or any other way) to pull a current time zone settings for a (US) city. For the parts of the country that don't follow the Daylight Saving Time and basically jump timezones when everyone else is switching summer/winter time... I don't fancy creating own database of the places that don't follow DST. Is there a way to pull this data on demand?

I need this for the database server (not for client workstations) - there entities stored in the database that have City, State as properties. I need know current timezone for these entities at any moment of time.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

earthtools.org provides a free web service to get the time zone from a city here:

http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone

You just pass in the long/lat values like this: (This is for New York)

http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/40.71417/-74.00639

---

**EDIT:**

It seems like earthtools has been shut down. A good alternative (That did not exist in 2008 when this question was answered) is the Google Time Zone API. To use it you must first [activate the Time Zone API](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=timezone_backend&keyType=SERVER_SIDE) on your account. It is free if you stay below these limits:

- 2500 requests per 24 hour period.
- 5 requests per second.

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro) is available on Google Developers.

Comment: what if we do not know the latitude/longitude information for a city?

Comment: EarthTools is great but since a week it's offset by 4 min. Great but does not seem reliable.

Comment: I add a few issues with http://earthtools.org especially when DST in involved. I would not recommend this webservice. I found http://www.timeanddate.com/ to be much more accurate, it is not free though.

Comment: i agree, DST support is very poor :(

Comment: I was using earthtools until I realized that they only have DST info for western Europe (and currently they say so on their page.)

Comment: As of 2015-09-09 it's not working. My app is in danger. How irresponsible!! I know it was free, but how can they just shut it down like that.

Comment: @Espo this API is No longer working , will you please provide any alternate option

Comment: @AtanuCSE I had a Tasker task that pinged it every morning to get the sunrise/sunset data for that day, based on my GPS location. Last good response I got was July 22.

Comment: link is broken now

Answer (score 73):

We encountered same issue and, alongside the great suggestions above, Google appears to have two complementary APIs, one for Time Zone from geocode (latitude/longitude) data and the geocode API.

For example, to get the time zone and offset for San Francisco:

#### 1) Convert the city to a geocoded location:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=San%20Francisco,+CA&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=San%20Francisco,%20CA&sensor=false)

The geocoded location is in the JSON return data:

```
"location": {
    "lat":  37.77492950,
    "lng": -122.41941550
}
```

#### 2)  Convert the geocoded location to a local timezone and offset, if any:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=37.77492950,-122.41941550&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false

Which returns the current time zone information:

```
{
          "status": "OK",
       "dstOffset":  0.0,
       "rawOffset": -28800.0,              
      "timeZoneId": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "timeZoneName": "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

Time zones for a region can change for a variety of reasons.  So it is a good idea to find an authoritative server-based solution and not cache. For more information see [Wikipedia's Time Zone article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Programming_languages).

Comment: Note, that you can pass non-English city name to the Google Geocode.

Comment: How do you compute current location time with this Google Timezone result ?

Comment: @NicolasThery Without looking at the API docs I'm guessing `rawOffset` is offset against UTC in seconds. So just add this value to a UTC timestamp and you're done.

Comment: @NicolasThery Sorry, it looks like you actually have to add `dstOffset` plus `rawOffset` to your UTC timestamp.

Comment: how to add a callback function here so it can be used on browser and avoid the cross domain security problem

Answer (score 16):

Geonames.org has a wonderful set of worldly data that's available via webservice or download:

http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html

In particular

http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone

.

Comment: However it doesn't allow to specify date,for which you want to find timezone offset

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the answer and it helps me a lot.
I need to ask you whether daylight saving time is implemented in it?
Let me know as i can't test it now? I need current time from lat long.

Answer (score 7):

Earthtool's timezone info is not up to date ... for an instance, the Sri Lankan current offset is +5.5 from GMT but EarthTools shows as +6 which was the old offset before 2005.

I suggest [GeoNames.org](http://GeoNames.org).

Answer (score 5):

[WorldTimeServer.com](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/time_zone_guide/) has what appears to be a comprehensive time zone database, which you can purchase access to in a variety of formats, including a .NET component for Web use.

No connection, just had to research the same thing myself recently.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Offline Library : [APTimeZones](https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones)

In order to find the time zone for a location you can use such as the Google Maps API’s time zone API. Unfortunately this requires you to query a remote service and you are subject to their limits.

Here’s a library rom Alterplay called [APTimeZones](https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones)(Git is attached) that allows you to extract an NSTimeZone from a given location without the need to connect to a remote service.   [APTimeZones](https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones) works by querying a local listing of time zones (included with the library).

Comment: I've rewritten this library in Java, so you can use it on Android devices also: https://github.com/agap/llttz

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone should bump into this question.

- You could use Google API to search for an address. That returns latitude / logitude. With those values in hand, you can find the closest timezone using e.g. PHP.
- Or you can use an API like timezoneapi.io (I'm behind that) which enables you to search for an address / city / country. It returns the address, the timezone information and the current date/time for that given timezone.

https://timezoneapi.io/developers/address

Comment: How updated is it kept? And does it provide timezone on the basis of Latitude and Longitude?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered, but I am posting this answer as people might still find it useful - The selected answer does not work successfuly right now.

Google have their own service, which is very reliable and easy to use, and outputs info in JSON format.  It even allows for specifying a custom time, e.g get the timezone in 02/02/2013 in Malta.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/

Comment: how to use it on browser with call back function or so to avoid the cross browser issue