# I need a list of cities and the corresponding timezone for an autocomplete text input

Tags: autocomplete

Where can i find city/timezone data to populate my autocomplete text input.

The text input will be used to type in a city, then behind the scenes i will use the city to get the time zone...

I would prefer to hold it within the app itself and not get it in realtime.

This will be for an iphone app.

Thanks,

m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this information for **any** city/town on earth, you'll need to use a webservice; there's no list of that as such. Look at this post for some recommendations: [Web service - current time zone for a city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city)

I can't see the csv mentioned above, but, if you were after a time zone and a few relevant cities inside the zone, PHP has a [DateTimeZone class](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

that will return all identifiers like this:

```
$data = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
```

Comment: for completion's sake: This list is just a PHP implementation of the [IANA Time Zone Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), but I'm sure you can access it somehow in most programming languages.

Answer (score 5):

if you download the windows mobile SDK in the resources folder is two csv files with city and timezone information. These files are free to redistribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458853.aspx