# free web service returning city names, city codes and time zone

Tags: java, web-services, timezone

Do you know a web service that's able let's say get a full list of cities in the world
with names, short names like PAR for Paris and time zones?

Or at least query by city name: Paris -> timezone=+02:00, abbrev=PAR

Also, what I see here: http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone

*offset
The number of hours offset from UTC disregarding any correction for daylight saving time.*

That's not a desired result. Of course we need this correction!

Comment: Similar questions with more answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at http://www.geonames.org

Comment: This answer should have been accepted