# Timezone for any city of any country in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, timezone

While programming an iPhone application, how can I find the timezone of any city / country?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [TimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city)

that might help you

Answer (score 0):

Look at [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/). It has a comprehensive web service, including time zone services.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Offline Library :

In order to find the time zone for a location you can use such as the Google Maps API’s time zone API. Unfortunately this requires you to query a remote service and you are subject to their limits.

Here’s a library rom Alterplay called [APTimeZones](https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones)(Git is attached) that allows you to extract an NSTimeZone from a given location without the need to connect to a remote service. [APTimeZones](https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones) works by querying a local listing of time zones (included with the library).