# Get timezone from a country

Tags: java, web-services

Can anyone tel me how to get a timezone name from city and country name? Any webservice link also will suffice my need..

For eg,
Input : Bangalore, India

Output is : IST

Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at this

  [Old Post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812249/how-can-i-get-with-the-timezone-the-countryname

Comment: Aside from the main question here, I would strongly discourage you from using abbreviations for time zone names. They become ambiguous *really* quickly. Use the Olson zoneinfo names (or possibly the subset from CLDR).

Comment: Have a look at the following question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262264/i-need-a-mapping-list-of-cities-to-timezones-best-way-to-get-it

Answer (score 0):

http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/search.html

Enter just the city name and it will give you all kinds of information, including the time zone.