# how to get the date-time for a particular city in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web service - current time zone for a city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city)

Just wondering whether there is a public web service (without reading from local machine time zone) that I could use to get the current date-time in that city using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org) to get the time zone. From that and the current UTC time, you can work out the local time. (You can also download the GeoNames data to avoid having to make a remote call.)

Note that GeoNames uses the Olson time zone names - there are various mappings from those to Windows time zone names around on the net for use with [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx), or (plug) you could use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) to perform the UTC to local time conversion. While there are aspects of Noda Time which are unfinished, that part should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) has one.

Answer (score 0):

There would have to exist a way for a Computer to know where it was located.

Computers, by and large, have no idea where they are.

That said, you could write something into your code that could set/specify where it was, then go from there using UTC.

Answer (score 0):

A commercial one

http://worldtimeengine.com/api