# How to get a list of all cities in the world and their correponding time zone information including DST

Tags: c#, list, timezone, dst, city

As the title says, is there any way to get ahold of this information?

Comment: "All the cities in the world" would be a very large list. You would be  better querying a database for the city you want.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think you need to specify some more constraints in order to get a good answer. What language and platform? What operating system? etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web service - current time zone for a city?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, you can use the `System.TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` method to get a list of all of the timezones in the world, including DST information.  This doesn't tell you which cities are in which timezones, however.  For that you would need some sort of third-party database.

You should also take a look at this question: [Web service - current time zone for a city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city).