# TimeZone Database for c++ under Windows and Linux

Tags: boost, timezone

Does anybody know a TimeZone database which I can use with C++ under Windows(with MinGW) and under Linux?

It is not enought to Convert Times into different TimeZones, I need History-Data of Timezones(including UTC offset and DayLightSaving Time.

I found a few, for example ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tz-link.html but I did not find a parser for c++

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8319571/11343

Comment: You definately want the IANA/Olson time zone database.  Don't use the ones that come with Windows.  The link you gave, and CharlesB's linked answer both point at ICU for a C++ implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!
I have tried following example:

```
    time_t time1 = makeTime(1975, 7, 2,10, 11, 41);
time_zone_ptr utc_tz(new posix_time_zone("UTC-00:00:00"));
local_date_time timeutc(toPtime(time1), utc_tz);

time_zone_ptr cet_tz = tz->tz_db.time_zone_from_region("Europe/Berlin");
local_date_time timecet(toPtime(time1), cet_tz);

cout<<timeutc<<endl; // Output: 1975-Jul-02 10:11:41 UTC
cout<<timecet<<endl; // Output: 1975-Jul-02 12:11:41 CEST
```

According to Wikipedia there was no Summertime in Germany from 1950 to 1979.
But as you can see in the output, the result is in CEST

Do I have to do any special to use historic Timezonedata with boost?

Thanks
Florian