# How do I set TZ env var to CET in visual C?

Tags: visual-c++, timezone

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char env_TZ[] = "TZ=CET";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    time_t submissionTime = 1359120032;
    struct tm local_time;
    char str[30];
    int ofsmm;

    putenv(env_TZ);
    tzset();
    printf("%s (%s)\n", tzname[0], tzname[1]);
    local_time = *localtime(&submissionTime);
    strftime(str, sizeof(str), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &local_time);
    ofsmm = -(int)(timezone/60) + (local_time.tm_isdst?60:0);
    printf("%s %+05d\n", str, ofsmm/60*100 + ofsmm % 60);
    return 0;
}
```

What should be in env_TZ? Definitely not "CET": it sets timezone to zero.
Where's the list of supported values?
It seems that the name I use doesn't matter in visual C, what matters is the number after, for example "FOO-1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezone handling in C++ is designed around POSIX style time zones, such as `PST8PDT`.  There isn't a predefined list, but rather a format for describing the time zone rules.  They are limited in that they only let you define the *current* rule.  They have no way to express changes to those rules.

You might want to refer to the following documentation links:

- [tzset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90s5c885.aspx)
- [localtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx)

In particular, the following bits stand out for MS Visual C++:

> If the TZ environment variable is set, the C run-time library assumes rules appropriate to the United States for implementing the calculation of daylight-saving time (DST).

And more troubling:

> TZ is a Microsoft extension and not part of the ANSI standard definition of localtime.

So it probably doesn't support the full POSIX time zone extended formats, such as the ones described in [this excellent writeup by IBM for AIX](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-posix/).

I am really not certain if it does or doesn't support the extended format, you would have to check.  I found the full correct POSIX style `TZ` variable for Central European Time [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19957), which is:

```
CET-1CEST,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3
```

If it doesn't support the extensions the best you could do is `CET-1CEST` - but that would end up using US daylight transition rules rather than the European ones.

You could consider using Boost, since it appears to have full support for [POSIX time zones](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#date_time.local_time.posix_time_zone).

But what you probably want to do instead is use the [IANA/Olson](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) standard time zone database.  This format of time zone would be specified by something like `Europe/Paris`, and supports the full history of time zone changes in the area you specify.  There appears to be a C++ implementation in a [library called ICU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319571/634824).  You can see a list of valid zones in this format [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Time zones are much harder in native code then they are in managed .Net code.  If there's any way you can run .Net code instead, I highly recommend using [Noda Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/), which provides a full IANA/Olson database internally.  You could also use Windows time zones via the .Net [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) class, but they're not as standardized as IANA zones.

Comment: So, there's no way to define european dst using crt.

Comment: What happens when you try the extended posix string?

Comment: nothing. From "CET-1CEST,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3" it reads only "CET-1CES".

Comment: I wonder how Windows XP handled the cancellation of DST in Russia, since DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION appeared only in Vista

Comment: They did it by issuing a patch to the DST rules.  [Read here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mthree/archive/2011/04/22/russia-042211.aspx)