# Get time(zone) of a location

Tags: java, android

So far I have thought about

Location - this has getTime() but I don't know how to set the location as a string instead of device location

```
String citytocheck = edittext.gettext().toString();
```

citytocheck is the name of a city/country/location here

How can I accomplish this? Even getting the timezone would be fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();  
        SimpleDateFormat sdf;  
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");  
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));  

    }

}
```

Comment: No. I don't need local device time. I need the time or time-zone of the location provided by edittext.