# How to get online date in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

> How to get online date in vb.net ? is this possible ?
>
> i use this code but it gives error like this (The remote server
>   returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.) can anyone help ? thank you in advance

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
    Private Function getPageSource(ByVal URL As String) As String
        Dim getWebClient As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim strSource As String = getWebClient.DownloadString(URL)
        getWebClient.Dispose()
        Return strSource
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myPageSource, myStr, myStr1, strDate As String
        Dim curLen, myStrPos, setStartPos As Integer
        Dim dt As DateTime

        txtPageSource.Text = getPageSource("http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_PH.aspx")
        myPageSource = txtPageSource.Text

        'code to trim all the text till TIME start position
        myStr = ""
        myStrPos = myPageSource.IndexOf(myStr)
        txtPageSource.Text = txtPageSource.Text.Remove(1, myStrPos + 23)
        myPageSource = txtPageSource.Text

        'code to trim all the text till after DATE
        curLen = Len(txtPageSource.Text)
        myStr1 = "2010"
        setStartPos = myPageSource.IndexOf(myStr1)
        txtPageSource.Text = txtPageSource.Text.Remove(setStartPos + 4, curLen - setStartPos - 4)

        'code to trim "" and "" tags in between TIME and DATE
        ' 6:27 AM
        ' 
        '
        'Wednesday, June 23, 2010
        txtPageSource.Text = txtPageSource.Text.Replace("", "")
        txtPageSource.Text = txtPageSource.Text.Replace("", "")

        strDate = txtPageSource.Text
        dt = CType((TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(New DateTime(2000, 1, 1)).ConvertFrom(strDate)), DateTime)
        'txtPageSource.Text = dt
        MsgBox(dt)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Heard of [NIST](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi)?

Comment: not sir what is that ?

Comment: Check below posts. It offers better and reliable solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city