# Get timezone from country and state in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, timezone, location

So from an input like the country: **US** and state: **CA** I'd need to get the timezone.

I saw this response here: [Get timezone directly from Country and State Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045745/get-timezone-directly-from-country-and-state-google-api), but the problem is that Google API needs longitude and latitude, so I wonder if I first need to look for these values. Is there any option to get the timezone directly?

Thank you

Comment: have you also the current time? And then the result should be +3 +2 ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Edit your question to add the things you've tried thus far.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have the current time but need to convert to UTC, so to know the user time zone I know the country and the state we have in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) gives you some functionality to do this

I have installed it with `npm install moment-timezone`

Then you can get the TimeZone as follows here for California using Los_Angeles

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();

var a = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Los_Angeles");
var b = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");



console.log(a.format()); // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-08:00
console.log(b.format()); // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00

console.log(a.utc().format()); // 2013-11-18T19:55:00Z
console.log(b.utc().format()); // 2013-11-18T16:55:00Z
```

Comment: That’s actually a good option, I’d just to convert country and state ISO2 codes to long version. LA - Los_Angeles. Thank you, I’ll try this out

Answer (score 0):

check this https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

```
var timestamp = 1403454068850,
    date = new Date(timestamp);

moment.tz(timestamp, "America/Los_Angeles").format(); // 2014-06-22T09:21:08-07:00
moment(timestamp).tz("America/Los_Angeles").format(); // 2014-06-22T09:21:08-07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this npm module [countries-and-timezones](https://www.npmjs.com/package/countries-and-timezones)

```
const ct = require('countries-and-timezones');
     
const timezone = ct.getCountryForTimezone('Asia/Tokyo');
console.log(timezone);
```

Comment: Interesting option thank you, I’m missing an easy way to find the state time zone though, anyways I’ll investigate more about this package